# How to start using Delta function in Microsoft graph by skipping initial data

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

Microsoft recommends to use delta function in combination with Subscriptions/Notifications to synchronize mailbox. So my plan is:

1. Create subscription
2. Receive notification about new mail in inbox
3. Use delta function to get latest changes in the inbox

My mailbox already has several thousands of letters. If I run the query
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/mailFolders/inbox/messages/delta`
It will return in response @odata.nextLink with $skiptoken param many times and only after I get all the thousands of emails in my mailbox I will receive response with $deltatoken to track new changes.

Is there a way to get deltatoken after the first request? I don't want to synchronize the old messages. I want to skip all old messages in inbox and have a fresh start.

Answer (score 0):

Today the delta query functionality does not support this scenario. To request new features please post ideas to [uservoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com)

Answer (score 0):

This is supported for *some* endpoints. You can use `$deltaToken=latest` to get just a deltaToken without any resource data. It's not, as far as I can tell, available for mailboxes… but who knows, maybe it will be soon.

This is not documented anywhere in the documentation for the specific APIs that *do* support it, but is instead documented in the [Overview for change tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0). Why? Because Microsoft wants you to be sad all the time.